# ExtJs 4 How to Increase width of panel dynamically?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

When i add new buttons to panel i wants to increase the size of that panel dynamically?

```
 Ext.onReady(function() {

    Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init();

     Ext.define('myPanel', {
        extend:'Ext.panel.Panel',
        bodyStyle  : {"background-color":"#DFE8F6","padding":"2px"},
            width:100,
        border:false,
        viewConfig: 
        {
            forceFit: true,
        }
        });

    new myPanel({
        id:'_panel',
            renderTo:Ext.getBody()
    });
        new Ext.button.Button({
        text:'Click Me',
        renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
        handler:function()
        {
            Ext.getCmp('_panel').add(new Ext.button.Button({text:'hello'}));
            Ext.getCmp('_panel').doLayout();
        }
     });
});
```

Here the width is 100.
When i add new buttons to panel the width of the panel should be increased as per new buttons.
Here buttons' sizes will be different for different texts of the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because ExtJS' Components have the functions for their width, so I think you can try:

```
handler:function()
    {
        var btn = new Ext.button.Button({text:'hello'});
        var panel = Ext.getCmp('_panel');
        panel.setWidth(panel.getWidth() + btn.getWidth());
        panel.add(btn);
        panel.doLayout();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you set `maxWidth` or `minWidth` property? For example if you set `maxWidth` to 100 and try to `setWidth(120)` dynamically it won't work.

This is what happened to me. My Sencha Architect UI designer set max width of a panel and I was trying to `setWidth()` more than the max value.

Wasted an hour for such a silly thing! :(